# Selective function register with xslt PHP

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I have a class which is made of only static methods. I want to register the class so that XSLT engine can use it. As far I am aware [`XSLTProcessor::registerPHPFunctions()`](http://php.net/xsltprocessor.registerphpfunctions) either registers all class and functions unless first parameter `$restrict` is passed and first param only takes method name in string or as array. How to register a whole class to XSLT so that all static method of a class can be accessible from xslt page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a class named `Foo`, you can get an array of all the class methods with code like this:

```
function addClassPrefix($name) {
  return "Foo::$name";
}
$names = array_map("addClassPrefix", get_class_methods("Foo"));
```

Note the need to add the class name as a prefix in front of each method name.

You can then simply register the whole array like this:

```
$proc = new XSLTProcessor();
$proc->registerPHPFunctions($names);
```